# Is it possible to capture audio sent to the audio interface using QAudioProbe?

Tags: qt, audio, qtmultimedia, probe

For my application, I need to visualize the audio signal that's sent to an audio interface (core audio/hardware sound card), without needing to forward the signal (this is how `soundflower` or `jack audio` work).

One example is that QuickTime player allows the user to record whatever is playing at the moment. I need the same ability to capture audio but in my case I'll visualize the signal.

Is it possible to use `QAudioProbe` and `QMediaObject` to achieve this?

Comment: You need to capture all the sounds ***sent*** to a given sound card, without any media player started?

Comment: @VladimirBershov Yes! For example, if someone sent sounds from audacity directly to the soundcard, or if someone played music from the browser and sent it to the sound card, I would like to capture them.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is most likely impossible without using additional virtual audio driver https://stackoverflow.com/q/44507956/4149835